# Adding a click away event without having to click twice to make it reappear in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue where I'm able to get an element to disappear when I click away from it but when I click on the icon that makes it visible again, I have to do it twice. Nothing will happen when I click just once.

```
const onClickOutside = (e) => {
const notificationsContainer = document.getElementById('notifications-container')
  if (!e.target.id.includes(notificationsContainer)) {
    notificationsContainer.style.display = 'none'
  }
};

window.addEventListener("click", onClickOutside);
```

I should only have to click the icon once to get it to show again.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: `!e.target.id.includes(notificationsContainer)` will always be `true`. You are trying to check if an `Element` object is included in a `string`.

Comment: How will that code ever make something reappear? It's only setting `display =  'none'` but never setting any other value for display

Comment: there are unclear conditions in your question. As already pointed out in comments, the correct condition would be something like `e.target !== notificationsContainer` but yet it's not clear how you are expected to click on an hidden element to make it reappear again

Comment: @derpirscher That code shouldn't make anything reappear. But this code is disabling the user's ability to make the element appear on first click as opposed to second click. So I'm trying to figure out what in the code is causing this and what can I add to resolve this issue.

Comment: @connexo What if I'm clicking on the element with the id of notificationsContainer? So the id would be referring to the actual HTML element rather than the text including the id? Wouldn't e.target.id !== notificationsContainer be better? You don't click on the hidden element to make it reappear again, you click on an icon to make that element visible.

Comment: @DiegoD ^^^^^^^

Comment: Well, maybe if you show all of your related code (ie also how the reappearing would happen) we would be able to help you better ... Because it may as simple as, if you click on your "icon" (what ever that may be) also the `onClickOutside` may be triggered again. Therefore typically questions should contain a minimal reproducible example that shows the faulty behaviour ...

Comment: @derpirscher I've tried looking in the dev tools because that part is being done with Bubble. I haven't been able to find the code though, otherwise I would have posted it. I'm pretty sure the display is being set to ' ' through Bubble but as I said I'm having difficulty confirming that.

Comment: @Harri your words both in the question and in comments totally invalidate the code you shared. That code would never work.. not once not twice. This `!e.target.id.includes(notificationsContainer)` alone doesn't make sense. I suggested a valid condition before to replace with, so that at least something happens. But yet you described your page as an icon that triggers the visibility of an another element but your code actually attempts (doing it wrongly) to hide a target element when clicking anywhere in the document except the target itself. Very very confusing question

Comment: @DiegoD You don't need to tell me that the code would never work. I posted the code on here for precisely that reason. Your 'valid condition' also hasn't done anything for me. Again, clearly, my code is doing it wrongly. If the code was doing it correctly I wouldn't need to make a post about it. Besides, it is actually hiding the target element correctly but the issue it's causing me is that I have to double click on the icon to make it reappear again instead of single clicking. I wrote this in the original post.

Comment: my comment was aimed at making things more clear because are confused. When I said that the code would never work was to stress that the condition you used is wrong because you passed an object instead of a string to the `.includes()` call. Your code will always hide the element even if the click comes from the target element because the condition will always be `true`. But yet the rest of the question is still missing the trigger the icon you are talking about. You had two answers already but didn't lead to the correct answer yet. Why? Because you are not addressing the point

Comment: I've already explained why I didn't post the logic involving the icon. I guess I should have posted this on the Bubble forum. Yeah I understand what you said and I acknowledged and implemented it. I appreciate the help but that didn't solve the issue I was trying to solve. Again, I probably should have posted the problem on Bubble but it's a nocode platform and my issue mainly pertains to code.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue once, to fix this, you need to remove the `onClickOutside` function from the `window` object when the `notificationsContainer` is hidden. You can do this by `removeEventListener` & I've also replaced `id.includes` to `contains`.

```
const onClickOutside = (e) => {
  const notificationsContainer = document.getElementById('notifications-container');
  if (!notificationsContainer.contains(e.target)) {
    notificationsContainer.style.display = 'none';
    window.removeEventListener("click", onClickOutside);
  }
};

window.addEventListener("click", onClickOutside);
```

Hope This will help....!

Comment: This solves the double-click problem but the event removal disables the ability to set the display to none. Also, it seems .contains is from Java so .includes would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @Harri No `contains` is fine here. There is no `.includes` method on DOM-nodes

Comment: Okay, thank you. Not sure why other threads are saying ```.contains``` doesn't exist in JavaScript.

Comment: @Harri That's true for `String.prototype` and `Array.prototype`. You seem to be confusing the prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make it reappear again with `onclick` events. Then, do `.stopPropagation()` for making a priority of clicking the `notificationsButton` instead of clicking the `window`.

```js
const notificationsContainer = document.getElementById('notifications-container');
const notificationsButton = document.getElementById('notifications-button');

notificationsButton.onclick = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (notificationsContainer.style.display === '') {
    notificationsContainer.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    notificationsContainer.style.display = '';
  }
}

window.onclick = (e) => {
  if (!notificationsContainer.contains(e.target)) {
    notificationsContainer.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#notifications-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button id="notifications-button">Notifications</button>
<div id="notifications-container">
  <ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>Try to click area outside div</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I want the element to simply disappear when I click away from it.

Comment: @Harri... here is one thing that made the problem harder to understand. The snippet provided actually performs the logic to hide the element when you click outside of it and also adds the supposed _"icon"_ to make it reappear. The icon is a button in this case. What do you mean saying that you just want to simply hide the element when you click away? isn't what is happening already here?

Comment: @Harri may you need to drink some water first.